# jQuery how to use on() with an if statement

Tags: jquery, delegates, live, addclass

I have an if statement that is currently working fine:

```
if ($('div').hasClass('is-sticky')) {
  $('body').addClass('has-sticky');
}
```

However the class ".is-sticky" is dynamically added to the markup from a different jQuery plugin.  So I figured out I needed to use on() in order to constantly watch for that class being added or removed.  But I can't figure out how to use on() with my current if statement.

I'd like to watch for ".is-sticky" being dynamically added and removed, and then addClass of ".has-sticky" to the body when it is present.

Thanks!

Comment: No this is not what `on` is for...

Comment: Since it's pretty established that you cannot monitor classes like this ( at least not without MutationObservers ), what are you actually trying to accomplish by monitoring that class?  Maybe someone can suggest a better way.

Comment: What I'd like to do is watch for the class, ".is-sticky" to be dynamically added to a div.  If that class is there, then my jQuery will add a class to the body tag.  

I thought `live()` could watch for selectors now and in the future, and since that's depricated, I thought `on()` would do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` is for binding event handlers to a selector whose matching elements may change dynamically. But you're not binding an event handler (there's no event triggered when classes are changed), so it doesn't help in this case.

You could use `setInterval()` to check periodically and update the class:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('has-sticky', $('div').hasClass('is-sticky'));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.on()` to monitor for when a class is added or removed from a DOM object.  jQuery doesn't offer that capability.

The kinds of things you can do to try to see when a class is modified are:

1. After any of the operations that might modify the class (you should know these if it's all your code), then you can call a function that tests the class and carries out its work if the class has been changed.
2. You can change all the places in your code that modify that class to either fire your own custom change event or call your own function and you can then do your work by handling that event or in that function.
3. You can use an interval timer to poll the DOM and look for changes (not recommended).
4. You can investigate whether any of the [DOM mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) can do what you want and are supported in enough browsers to solve your issue.

Comment: `live()` is described as:  Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

So I thought `on()` sould be able to match selectors added in the future, since it's said to have replaced `live()`

I'm not a JS guy, so I just barely get by on what I know how to do with jQuery.  Any other suggestions to achieve what I want would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mark.C - `.on()` registers event handlers for events like "click" or "keydown" or "mousemove", etc....  Changing a class on a DOM object does not cause any sort of event thus, `.on()` isn't of any use in watching for a class change.  If the browser had an event call `classChanged` that fired on any DOM object when a class was modified, you'd be in heaven with `.on("classChanged")`, but such a thing doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom trigger whenever you add this .is-sticky class to an element?

The trigger handler will be something like:

```
$('body').on('classAdded', function() {
   $(this).addClass('has-sticky');
});
```

And the trigger block will be like:

```
function whatever() {
   // logic that adds the class to $('div') .......
   // at this point, your $('div') has the is-sticky class already right?
   $('body').trigger('classAdded');
}
```

The trigger block will be like any other event like click/mouseenter that will call the handler. Though this can be a function call as well.....

Answer (score 0):

This is probably pretty hacky, but you could define a very short CSS transition for that `is-sticky` class, then bind to the `transitionend` event.  Using that, you should be able to know when that particular class has been added in IE10+ and the evergreen browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend